# "Augmenting" a category by an associative binary operation

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let ${\bf C}$ be a category, and $\zeta$ an associative binary operation on a set $I$. Define a $5$-tuple $(D_o,D_h,u,v,d)$ as follows: $D_o$ is just the object class of $\bf C$, while $D_h$ is the quotient of $\coprod_{i \in I} \hom({\bf C})$ by the equivalence $\mathcal R$ that amalgamates two pairs $(f,i)$ and $(g,j)$ iff $f=g={\rm id}_{\bf C}(A)$ for some $A \in {\rm Ob}({\bf C})$; $u$ and $v$ are the functions $D_h \to D_o$ taking the equivalence class $(f,i) \bmod \mathcal R$ to $s(f)$ and $t(f)$, respectively; and $d$ is the mapping $D_h \times_{v,u} D_h \to D_h$ sending a pair $((f,i)\bmod \mathcal R,(g,j) \bmod \mathcal R)$ to $(f,i) \bmod \mathcal R$, respectively to $(g,j) \bmod \mathcal R$, if $g$, respectively $f$, is an identity of $\bf C$, and to $(fg,\zeta(i,j)) \bmod \mathcal R$ otherwise.

It is clear that $(D_o,D_h,u,v,d)$ is a category, let me denote it by $\zeta \ast \bf C$. Since I don't know if  $\zeta \ast \bf C$ has already a name, I'm calling it the augmentation of $\bf C$ by $\zeta$: While looking forward to finding something more "natural", I'm using it as a toy example in reference to the idea of a generalized notion of limit which, on the one hand, can make sense in more abstract settings than categories (e.g., [Mitchell's semicategories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semicategory), or even Ehresmann's neocategories [1]), and on the other hand, *may perhaps* be an effective surrogate of limits in situations where limits do not exist and neither [weak limits](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weak+limit) nor sublimits (see note 2) are likely to represent, for some reason, a satisfactory alternative. So, here are my questions:

> > **Q1.** Is $\zeta \ast \bf C$, up to equivalence, a disguised form/a special instance of anything familiar to you? **Q2.** Does it satisfy any "obvious" universal property? **Q3.** Is it maybe a particular colimit (see note 2)?

Thanks in advance, as always, for any hint.

**Notes.** (1) Sublimits are the same as weak limits, save for the fact that we replace "at least" with "at most". (2) Say, as an object of ${\bf Cat}(\mathcal U)$, for a sufficiently large universe $\mathcal U$.

**Bibliography.**

[1] A. Bastiani and C. Ehresmann, *Categories of sketched structures,* Cahiers Topologie Géom. Différ. Catégoriques, Vol. 13, No. 2 (1972), 104-214.

Comment: I am likely confused about some aspect of your construction, but I don't see how $\zeta \ast C$ can be a category unless $\zeta: \alpha\times\alpha \to \alpha$ is associative.  If $\zeta$ is associative, then this is (almost, but not quite) the operation of "base change" of a category: if $C$ is any category, and $(\alpha,\zeta,a\in\alpha)$ any associative algebra, then "$C \otimes \alpha$" is the category with the same objects as $C$ and morphisms $\hom_{C\otimes \alpha}(x,y) = \hom_C(x,y)\times \alpha$.  I have no useful comments about colimits.

Comment: Thanks, Theo, for your comment. Yes, sorry, I forgot to say that $\zeta$ must be associative, in the categorial case. Let me edit and fix it. 

Comment: Even if $\zeta$ is associative, the composition in $\zeta * C$ is typically not associative, so it is not a category. Suppose that $f$ is an isomorphism in $C$ which is not an identity, and let $g$ be an arrow in $C$ with the same codomain. Then consider the two ways to compose $(f,i)\circ (f^{-1},j) \circ (g,k)$. If you do the left composition first, you get $(g,k)$. If you do the right composition first, you get $(g,ijk)$ where I'm writing the operation of $\zeta$ as concatenation. Typically $ijk \neq k$ so these do not agree.